# Always returns a undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jQuery to send Ajax request to the server to save the values being input in the form. Below the section where I am stuck. The HTML is as

```
<span class="no-margin multiple Date_Off" style="margin-left: 104px;">
  <input type="text" value="" /><input type="text" />
  <input type="text" value="-" /><input type="text" />
  <input type="text" /><input type="text"  value="-" />
  <input type="text" /><input type="text" /><input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</span>
```

I have tried using jQuery to send the request. What I want to do is something like this

1. I want to save the values from the form, to the same Column_Name that the input fields have. In the multiple input fields I am not using input names. Instead I am using a classname which is identical to the Column_Name in the database.
2. For that, I am using `$(this).parent().attr('class');`. If I use this in an alert, it gives me the result without error. But if I use it in the code, it gives me `undefined`.
3. I want to append each input's value to the string to save it as a single string.

Here is what I tried so far

```
var input = $('input');
input.change(function () {
// Input click function...
 if ($(this).parent().attr('class')
                    .replace(' multiple ', '')
                    .replace('no-margins', '') == 'Date_Off') {
  // Date Time for the office work!
  var value = '';
  value = $(this).parent().find('input').each(function (index, ele) {
     value += ele.val();
  });
     send_request('Date_Off', value);
// Below is the else condition, to execute only when the input is single
// Like a single string input and not like the one in image
// That's why I am using attr('name') for that.
 } else {
     send_request($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());
 }
});
```

But what it returns is always a undefined in the Query structure. Here is the function for that

```
function send_request(input_name, value) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax_requests/save_form',
    data: 'input_name=' + input_name + '&form_id=' +     
    $('input[type=hidden]').val() + '&value=' + value,
    error: function () {
      $('.main-content').append(
         'There was an error in request. 
          Please contact your website Developer to fix it.'
       );
    },
    success: function () {

    }
  });
}
```

#### Image for the code execution

[image]

The input in focus was `1. Date`. And the console shows the Internal Server Error. Because jQuery sent the request with `input_name=undefined` which is not a Column_Name.

I have created a (Mini) fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/EHWqB/

Any help here?

Comment: You say you are using the parent class but then you pass the name attribute `send_request($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());` doesn't make sense

Comment: I am sorry @Wilmer, I have clarified that point :) I am using an if else block to check if the input is single or multiple block...name is used for single inputs and className for multiples inputs...

Comment: or better yet you can do `if( $(this).parent().hasClass("Date_Off") )` edit: nevermind my previous suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In this line you're trying to get the name of the input

```
send_request($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());
```

I don't see a "name" attribute anywhere in your code, I think what you want is to get the class of the parent instead?

```
send_request($(this).parent().attr('class'), $(this).val());
```

Comment: Yes, I want to get the class of the parent element! But I don't get where is the error in my code.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan in the input.change function when you send request, you are using `attr('name')` which gets for example `<input name='abc'>` and returns 'abc', you should use `attr('class')`

Answer (score 0):

For the fiddle that you posted, there were two errors. The first was you were calling `ele.val()`, but `ele` in this context is not a jQuery object - so you need to get the `value` property off of it. The second is that the jQuery `each` function operates on an array of objects and it's return value is that array of objects. You don't want your `value`, which should be a string, to be accepting that return value. Here is an [updated, working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9VYzG/)

```
    input.change(function () {
    // Input click function...
    var value = '';
    $(this).parent().find('input').each(function (index, ele) {
        value += ele.value;
    });
    send_request('Date_Off', value);
});
```